# PHP extension installed but not loading

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, libssh2

I'm trying to install php's ssh2 extension, and having a little bit of difficulty.  The file is there, it's just not loading into php.

First, I've installed ssh2 with:

```
 aptitude install libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php
```

(For what it's worth, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on Nginx.)

I can see that ssh2 is loaded using the modules command:

```
php -m |grep ssh2
ssh2
```

However, when I run my code, I get an undefined function error.

In my phpinfo() script, I can see that my php installation scans this directory for additional ini files: /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d. Listing the contents of that directory, I can see that my ssh2.ini is there:

```
ls /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d
mysqli.ini  mysql.ini  pdo.ini  pdo_mysql.ini  ssh2.ini
```

According to phpinfo again, the other four ini files are loaded. SSH2 is not.

I've also tried placing "extension=ssh2.so" directly in my php.ini file - /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini.  And yes - I've restarted my nginx server.

Am I missing something else?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use libssh2? Could you use an alternative library?

Comment: you need to restart php not nginx, `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Answer (score 4):

1. Set `display_startup_errors = On` in you php.ini
2. Set `error_log = '/var/log/php-error.log'` in you php.ini
3. Create error log - `touch /var/log/php-error.log`

Now, you can restart php5-fpm daemon and lookup in error log any errors with ssh2 module

Comment: How to restart the php daemon?

Comment: `sudo pkill php7.4-fpm; sudo service php7.4-fpm restart` seems like a good way to restart the daemon (replace with your version)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Aleksandr was helpful. I was attempting to install a PHP extension for a Plesk build. You need to make the modifications to the Plesk php.ini version that corresponds to the domain (which you can find in the web-based control panel under Tools and Settings). The error log will be located in /var/log/plesk-phpXX-fpm.

Do NOT uncomment the error_log (#2 / #3) as noted above otherwise you won't see the error show up in this location.