# OS X/Php - Extensions not loading

Tags: php, macos, php-extension, scrypt

I'm trying to use the scrypt extension for php from here https://github.com/DomBlack/php-scrypt.
I'm using OS X Yosemite and installed the extension via pecl, everything went fine.

The extension is located in /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/scrypt.so
In my php.ini(/etc/php.ini) I got

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226"
extension = scrypt.so
```

I'm using this php.ini https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.5.14/php.ini-development - Php Version is 5.5.14

I tried the extension_dir with and without slash at the end. But when I check via phpinfo scrypt is not loaded. What am I doing wrong? I tried it with other extensions and it seems like none of them load.

**Edit:**

I turned on php errors as suggested in this post: [PHP extension installed but not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305954/php-extension-installed-but-not-loading)

Now I got an error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: scrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Are you using MAMP? I had a similar issue and MAMP has different PHP ini files, which you can find in templates (I believe) in the top menu bar of the application.

Comment: I'm not using MAMP and I'm pretty sure about the php.ini because of phpinfo: Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini

Comment: Ok, just checking :) Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: Yes - via sudo apachectl restart. I even rebooted :)

Comment: Is there anything in the error log suggesting as to why it won't load?

Comment: Not really, I already checked the apache logs

Comment: Try to use full path to extension eg.
extension = "/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/scrypt.so"

Comment: I edited my start post